# Atom Script can't find the path for Python 3 on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos, atom-editor

When using the script addon for Atom it brings up:

> Unable to run
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/python3
> ```
>
> Did you start Atom from the command line?
>
> ```
> atom .
> ```
>
> Is it in your PATH?
>
> ```
> PATH: /usr/bin/python3:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/bin/python3:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:~/.dotnet/tools
> ```

How do I get Atom to recognize Python 3?

I tried installing Python using Homebrew and it is installed to `/usr/local/bin/python3` as well as using the Terminal to add all of the suggested path locations to `/etc/paths`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to properly configure the [**script** package](https://atom.io/packages/script) to use a profile that points to the correct `python3`.

1. Open a Terminal and navigate to the directory containing your scripts.

   ```sh
   $ pwd
   /Users/cerberus/Scripts
   ```
2. Get the path to `python3`

   - If you installed it via Homebrew, then it should be at:

     ```sh
     $ python3 -V
     Python 3.7.3
     $ which python3
     /usr/local/bin/python3
     ```
   - You can also check that Homebrew already updated `PATH` to add */usr/local/bin*, but unless you did something wrong with the Python installation, this part is unnecessary.

     ```sh
     $ echo $PATH
     .../usr/local/bin/:/...
     ```
3. Now, start Atom **from the command line** as explained in the [package docs](https://atom.io/packages/script)

   > Make sure to launch Atom from the console/terminal. This gives atom
   >   all your useful environment variables. Additionally, make sure to run 
   >   it with the project path you need.

   ```sh
   $ cd /path/to/scripts
   $ atom .
   ```

   OR

   ```sh
   $ atom /path/to/scripts
   ```
4. Go to *Packages* > *Command Palette* > *Toggle* (or use CMD+SHIFT+P)
5. Select ***Script**: Run Options*

[image: Script: Run Options]

6. Input the path to your scripts and the path to the `python3` command

[image: create profile]

> **NOTE:** On my machine, just setting `python3` also works. But if you are having problems with your python path, you can try to specify the full path (`/usr/local/bin/python3`) as shown.

7. Save the profile (ex. as "Python3")
8. Now, when you want to run your Python scripts, use the ***Script**: Run with Profile* command and then select the profile you just created.

[image: Script: Run with Profile]

[image: select profile]

9. That should work now.

[image: run successful]